# CSS transition on display property doesn't work

Tags: css, css-transitions

I've set up a function:

```
function removeDiv(el){
    var elem = document.getElementById(el);
    elem.style.transition = "display 2.5s linear 0s";
    elem.style.display = "none";    
}
```

and created a div which has the function called onclick.
However when I click on the div it disappears immediately without transitioning. Are display transitions not supported - can it be either one state like 'block' or another?
Thanks for looking!

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-display-property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`display` is not a property that can be animated. Try `opacity` instead.

For future reference, here is the official specification of all properties that can be animated: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-css